# google spreadsheet formula not working properly

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using this formula in google spreadsheet. The problem is if any other cell is changed in the sheet, this formula is giving a new result.

There are no event triggers for this sheet. Also, tested it on a new sheet with same result.

```
=if(G25,CONCATENATE(ARRAYFORMULA(CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(SEQUENCE(1, 8, 1, 0),3),CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(48,57)),CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90)),CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(97,122))))),)
```

appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

if you use `RANDBETWEEN` you have 3 options to choose from:

[image]

other options include not to use formula but script or spreadsheet [addon](https://spreadsheet-freezer.rubenrivera.mx/) to freeze your sheet

Comment: thank you. Will this change do not affect other spreadsheet formulae? On change means if there is a change in the worksheet or only G25 change?

Comment: "on change" means if any cell on any tab/sheet in your whole spreadsheet changes. it would be triggered even if you delete any empty cell